# Problem with binding VARCHAR2 parameters into EXECUTE IMMEDIATE statement

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a PL/SQL procedure that consumes two input parameters of type VARCHAR2 (`amount` is nullable, `exact_amount` is just a true/false flag but Oracle does not support boolean types):

```
amount           in VARCHAR2,
exact_amount     in VARCHAR2,
```

In the procedure, I build a `select` using `execute immediate` statement:

```
execute immediate 'select ... from ... where ...
          and (nvl(:amount, ''null'') = ''null'' or (:exact_amount = ''1'' and TO_CHAR(TOTAL_VALUE) = :amount) or (:exact_amount = ''0'' and (TO_CHAR(TOTAL_VALUE) = :amount OR TO_CHAR(TOTAL_VALUE) LIKE '''||amount||'.%'')))'

bulk collect into ids
            using ... amount, exact_amount, amount, exact_amount, amount;
```

But the problem is, somehow the condition always evaluates to false and the whole `select` does not return any results. I have tried many combinations of binding varchar params but none of them work properly so my question is what is the correct syntax?

Comment: Why are you using dynamic SQL? Your query looks like it could be static. And why are you comparing numbers as strings; and passing `amount` as a string? (You should at least specify the format if you have a good reason to do that).

Comment: I'm not the author of the query, full procedure is much more complex and I have to add just one extra condition to the where clause (really dont want to refactor it). Using varchar instead of numeric types is more elastic for me since there is a Java client to this query and few possibilites like searching by the same value or similiar (LIKE at the end of clause), using Java Doubles generates extra work to deal with (eg in my query 2 and 2.00 means different types of searching, in Java double is always represents as 2.00)

Answer (score 0):

When constructing string for execute immediate there is usualy a problem with single quotes. Try to get your sql command using something like this:

```sql
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
Declare
    cmd     VarChar2(1000);
    sq    VarChar2(1) := '''';    -- single quote character
Begin
    cmd := 'select col_1, col_2, col_3  
            from a_table 
            where numeric_column  = ' || :numeric_bind_var || ' and char_column = ' || sq || :char_bind_vara || sq;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(cmd);
End;
```

... if your **:numeric_bind_var** is 100 and your **:char_bind_var** is 'ABC' then the sql command will be:

```sql
select col_1, col_2, col_3  
from a_table 
where numeric_column  = 100 and char_column = 'ABC'
```

I use sq (single_quote) variable declared and initialized with '''' (four single quotes) which is represented as a single quote in construction of a sql command.
When you get a working sql command contained in the cmd variable then you can do

```sql
--  ...  ...  ...
execute immediate cmd
--  ...  ...  ...
```

Puting two single quotes like **''null''** or **''1''** will end up throwing an error. Regards...